# how to call hyperledger composer written chaincode from hyperledger fabric java sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have written my chaincode using hyperledger-composer and I have a function called Modify. I am trying to call this function from my java application using the hyperledger java sdk but I can't figure out how to call this function. I am getting the following error:

> Sending proposal to xxx.xxx.com failed because of: gRPC
>   failure=Status{code=UNKNOWN, description=error executing chaincode:
>   transaction returned with failure: Error: Unsupported function
>   "com.xxx.xxx.Modify" with arguments...

My question is how can I figure out the name of the function composer is creating in the chaincode when I create this modify transaction from composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used Hyperledger Composer to create your business network (.bna), you have to use the Hyperledger Composer SDK in you client application in order to interact with the blockchain ([API Reference](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/api-doc-index)).

Otherwise, you can use composer-rest-server ([official documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/rest-server)) to expose APIs of the business network.

Up to now, I don't think is available any Java SDK for Hyperledger Composer.